# Quick Volume of a Solid of Revolution Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"What is the volume of the solid generated when the region bounded by the graph of $x=\sqrt{(y-2)}$ and the lines $x=0$ and $y=5$ is revolved about the $y$-axis?"

I understand the "washer" and "disc" method and the application of both of these, but for some reason I'm stuck on what the formula for the volume of these equations would look like here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The volume is given by
$$
\int_2^5 A(y)\,dy
$$
where
$$
A(y)=\pi (\sqrt{y-2})^2
$$

---

Drawing a picture is helpful.

[image]

Comment: +1 : nice graphic

Comment: Looks like I'm coming up with about $14.13$, is that sounding right to you?

Comment: @joe yes that is correct.